# In ListView make only Buttons to be clickable

Tags: android

I have implemented a list view.

Each item in my list view has two elements - a TextView and a Button.

Now I have Implemented ArrayList Adapter in order to make my listview clickable.

Currently what is happening that whenever I click any element in my listview my OnItemClickListener is called.

Now what I want to do is that I want to make only my button clickabe and not the entire element.

Here is the code that I have  implemented.

```
public class SurveyListActivity extends ListActivity {


static private ArrayList<Survey> EU=new ArrayList<Survey>();

static {

        EU.add(new Survey(R.string.Survey1, R.drawable.completed,R.string.Survey1));
        EU.add(new Survey(R.string.Survey2, R.drawable.completed,R.string.Survey2));
        EU.add(new Survey(R.string.Survey3, R.drawable.inprogress,R.string.Survey3));
        EU.add(new Survey(R.string.Survey4, R.drawable.inprogress,R.string.Survey4));
        EU.add(new Survey(R.string.Survey5,R.drawable.inprogress,R.string.Survey5));
        EU.add(new Survey(R.string.Survey6, R.drawable.start,R.string.Survey6));

}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setListAdapter(new SurveyAdapter());
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v,int position, long id) 
{

    Toast.makeText(SurveyListActivity.this, "You Selected :- " + EU.get(position).name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

static class Survey 
{
    int name;
    int status;
    int result;

    Survey(int name, int status, int result) 
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.status=status;
        this.result=result;
    }
}

class SurveyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Survey> 
{
    SurveyAdapter() 
    {

        super(SurveyListActivity.this, R.layout.row, R.id.name, EU);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
    ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        SurveyWrapper wrapper=null;

        if (convertView==null) 
        {
            convertView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            wrapper=new SurveyWrapper(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(wrapper);
        }
        else 
        {
            wrapper=(SurveyWrapper)convertView.getTag();
        }

        wrapper.populateFrom(getItem(position),position);
        return(convertView);
    }
}

class SurveyWrapper 
{
    private TextView name=null;
    private ImageView status=null;
    private View row=null;

    SurveyWrapper(View row) 
    {
        this.row=row;
    }

    TextView getName() 
    {
        if (name==null) 
        {
            name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }
        return(name);
    }

    ImageView getstatus() 
    {
        if (status==null) 
        {
            status=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.flag);
        }
        return(status);
    }

    void populateFrom(Survey survey, int i) 
    {
        if((i%2)!=0)
        {

            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            getName().setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }
        getName().setText(survey.name);
        getstatus().setImageResource(survey.status);

    }
}

}
```

Comment: If I remove the onItemClickListener and just add the onClickListener to button, then in that case I will have the problem to see which item was selected as i have a single button only in the layout file with some id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onListItemClick` will do just that: respond to clicking anywhere on the item.  If you want to only part of the view in the item to be clickable, then do this in your `getView` in the adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    SurveyWrapper wrapper=null;

    if (convertView==null) 
    {
        convertView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        wrapper=new SurveyWrapper(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(wrapper);
    }
    else 
    {
        wrapper=(SurveyWrapper)convertView.getTag();
    }

    wrapper.populateFrom(getItem(position),position);
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_button).setOnClickListener(new onClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(SurveyListActivity.this, "You Selected :- " + EU.get(position).name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return(convertView);
}
```

And completely remove `onItemClickListener`.

Comment: @ Aleks G   -- it is showing error : - The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: @AdityaPratap a small misspelling - missed one word - fixed now.  You could correct that yourself, you know.

Comment: @cstrutton You don't need to.  `setOnClickListener` is a method in the `View`.  `Button` does not override it.

Comment: sorry... miss spoke and deleted it

Comment: Thanks Aleks G .. You Are a Life saver.  and sorry I wasn't able to find that I m kind of new to  Android

Answer (score 0):

If I under stand you correctly, you need to remove the onItemClickedListener and attach an onClick listener to the buttons. You should be able to set a generic button click listener in the row layout xml and determine which button is clicked through the view object's parent (which should be the ListView).

Answer (score 0):

Use custom adapter and then add setOnClickListener to the specific item (button)

```
Button btnAction= (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnAction);

btnAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                      @Override
                      public void onClick(View view) {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show(); 
                      }
                    });
```